# printer error waste-receptacle-full

Tags: ubuntu, printer

[image]

The image displays an error I receive when trying to print out from the printer. I am running Ubuntu and am trying to connect to the printer for the first time.

Here are some settings:

[image]

I actually have no idea about drivers etc. Anyone can shove me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help guys! It was a driver issue I finally found the drivers needed and then it all worked. Weird that I got that message though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is no hardware error with the waste bottle sensor, the problem is a physical one. Waste toner is saved in a waste receptacle which fills until it needs emptying.
The receptacle is easy to empty.

As shown in the photo below.

- Open front door and remove.
- Remove paper tray (the missing one in the photo :-).)
- Remove the screw holding the door at left closed.
- Open door.
- Pull out waste bottle - CAREFULLY - it's full of messy toner.
- Take waste bottle to rubbish and empty it. Take due care.Very messy.
- Replace in reverse order.
- Done.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Other users have reported this as a bug.  Bugzilla (https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1193105) suggests that a fix is available in CUPS 1.7.5 but I haven't been able to obtain this on Ubuntu 14.04LTS yet to verify it.

You can test whether you have this bug or a genuinely full waste receptacle either by opening the printer as described above, or by viewing the printer status from a PC (i.e. not CUPS) or the printer control panel.

In my case, CUPS is the only place it is reported as full, and the printer I use has a status bar which accurately reports a full waste receptacle.

Sorry this doesn't fix the problem, but at least you know not to keep trying to fix it yourself, and it's not your fault.